# How to fetch data from coreData with MR in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm trying to get data from coredata with MagicalRecord

code:

```
var userDetails:User!
userDetails = User.MR_findAll() as! User
```

Cast from '`[AnyObject]`' to unrelated type '`User`' always fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used MagicalRecord before, but you're trying to cast from an array of `AnyObject` to a single `User`... Did you mean to write:

```
let userDetails = User.MR_findAll() as! [User]
```

Comment: it dosent have a array ...as! [User].  It should be just a  ... as! User but display that exception

Comment: What doesn't have an array? Your problem is you're trying to cast from an array to an unrelated type - `User`.

Answer (score 2):

When ever you fetch it will be a `Array` type so make these changes

`var userDetails:[User]!`

`userDetails = User.MR_findAll()`

Which will give you the result of array of `User` type.